# Website with layout plans for LEGO Duplo trains?

Tags: trains, duplo, monorail

Can anybody suggest a web site with plans for LEGO Duplo trains?

I've searched the net for a while without any interesting results.
Any hints appreciated!

Answer (score 10):

I'm not aware of any sites that are dedicated to DUPLO train layouts, but there are certainly interesting layout ideas out there. For example, this was included in set 2932:

[image: 2932 ideas]

There are also loads of great creations in [this Pinterest category](https://www.pinterest.com/explore/lego-duplo-train/):

[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]