# What is the length of a DUPLO train bridge?

Tags: trains, duplo, bridge

I'm trying to plan a DUPLO train track layout to order but I currently don't own any pieces. I'd like to include a bridge like the one in [set 3774](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?O=3774-1), but I'm unsure if it will fit my layouts.

Can anyone tell what's the length of the bridge (it seems to be made up of parts [6393](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6393) and [6392](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6392), two of each) in DUPLO studs?

Comment: From the looks of it (by inspecting the image on Bricklink), the red bridge girder is 10 Duplo studs long.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the layouts from [this answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/8688/9723), a half-bridge seems to be 2 straight tracks + 1 quarter-circle (split mid-track at the end, because the middle of the bridge is centered with the crossing track below it).

From [this guy's](https://www.cailliau.org/Alphabetical/L/Lego/Duplo/Train/Rails/Dimensions/) measurements, a quarter-circle of the newer DUPLO tracks is about 18x18 studs. Straights are 8 studs long.

So, a half-bridge should be 32 studs (16+8+8), or 4 straight tracks. The full bridge would be 64 studs, or 8 straights.

**Note:** <strike>I don't have the pieces to confirm these measurements.</strike>

**Note 2:** I now have the pieces and can confirm these measurements, as shown in the picture below.
[image: bridge compared to 8 straights]